# Bash if statement gives opposite response than expected

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I think i'm missing something very obvious. But shouldn't the following code produce the opposite response? I thought if the statement "if s == d" is used and s is not equal to d then the if statement should return false and not run the following code. This is not what appears to happen. Can anyone explain what i've missed. I think it's something very obvious.

Thanks

```
s=2
d=3
if ! [ "$s == $d" ]; then         echo "hello"; fi
if [ "$s == $d" ]; then         echo "hello"; fi
hello
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing one of your echoed texts to differentiate which test succeeded. Also you could  use arithmetic expansion: `if (( s != d ))` and `if (( s == d ))` instead of `if ! [ "$s" == "d" ]` and `if [ "$s" == "$d" ]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for including a minimal, independent example. That makes it really easy to reproduce the problem and verify a fix.

Comment: By the way, if you paste this code into http://shellcheck.net/, it will link you to [SC2157](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2157), a wiki page describing the issue.

Comment: Thanks :) Wish i'd started asking questions on SO before, you guys respond so fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quoting the entire string `"$s == $d"` when you should be quoting the two arguments `"$s"` and `"$d"`.

This means that instead of comparing `$s` to `$d`, you are checking whether `"2 == 3"` is a non-empty string (which it is).

This will correctly print "not equal":

```
s=2
d=3
if ! [ "$s" == "$d" ]; then echo "not equal"; fi
if [ "$s" == "$d" ]; then echo "equal"; fi
```

Comment: Better to make it `[ "$s" = "$d" ]` so it also works on ash or dash, rather than sticking with `==` and relying on a shell that implements operators not given in the [`test` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).